# Calling native function from C# app

Tags: c#, c++

I have WinForms written in C#. I have C++ dynamic class library in my project. I need to call the native code from the C# app. S0, how do I call the C++ function below from my C# app.

```html
int printVals(void* thisInstance)
{
   myClass* thisClass = (myClass*) thisInstance;

   printf("Registered X: %d\n", ((int) thisClass->x));
   printf("Registered Y: %d\n", ((int) thisClass->y));
   printf("Registered Z: %d\n", ((int) thisClass->z));
   return 0;
}

typedef void (*callback)(void* thisInstance, char* message);

typedef struct myClassT
{
   callback thisCallback;
   char x;
   short y;
   long z;
} myClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I couldn't directly see which variables were inputs/outputs to your C# form. But this is how I did it:

- In your form.h file, include the header file of your C++ project.
- Between the declarations of the private variables of the form, include:

  `YourClass *yourObject = new YourClass();`
- Declare a function within your forms.h from where your c++ code will be called.
- In your forms.cpp file, implement your function and call your C++ function the normal way:

  `yourObject->yourFunction(Argument1, Argument2);`
- You will need to put some type conversions from your C# types to native types, for example to convert a double from a numericUpDown to a C++ double:

  `System::Decimal::ToSingle(this->numericUpDown1->Value);`

  For your data types, search the MSDN documentation on how to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for one function then you can use P/Invoke to call it from C# [P/Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#pinvoke_callingdllexport)
If you make a lot of calls to your C++ native library then you may have to consider using a C++/CLI project (reference the dll, include the headers and then call your functions).